# Jquery-Json.ParseUnexpected Character

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I have this following ajax to call my service which fetches some records from the Database and fills it in my frontend...but i get the json:unexpected character error...can u please help me in solving this ...

```
'http://localhost/WcfService/Service1.svc/remarksList';

    var tempyear="";

    $.ajax({
                    url: urlToHandler,
                    data:JSON.stringify({oei:{"reqNo1":reqNo,"loginid":userid}}),
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType:"json",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(data) {    

                    alert(data.fillRemarksListResult);
                    myData = JSON.parse(data.fillRemarksListResult, function (key, value) {
        var type;
        if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
            type = value.type;
            if (typeof type === 'string' && typeof window[type] === 'function') {
                return new (window[type])(value);
            }
        }
        return value;
    });
    alert(myData);
        $.each(data.fillRemarksListResult,function(key,val){


                alert(val.rmrkreqNo1);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(data, status, jqXHR) {                       
                        alert('There was an error.');
                    }
                }); // end $.ajax

});
```

**Now i get this error :**

**Json.parse:unexpected character
myData=JSON.parse(data.fillRemarksListResult, function (key, value) {**

Comment: What is inside the `data.fillRemarksListResult` (You can check this with `console.log()`)?

Comment: How does your json data looks?

Comment: Dont use JSON.parse. Just do console.log or again do stringify the JSON data to find out the error.

Comment: my data.fillRemarksListResult contains the response objects..

Comment: How do i do it ?? can u demonstrate it and show Yadheendran ??

Comment: Object { reqrmrkDate1="23/01/13", rmrkDesc1="-Enter your Query-", rmrkfrom1="800008", more...}, 
Object { reqrmrkDate1="23/01/13", rmrkDesc1="Allot the budget", rmrkfrom1="800008", more...}, 
Object { reqrmrkDate1="23/01/13", rmrkDesc1="-Enter your Query-", rmrkfrom1="800008", more...}, 16 more...]
0 Object { reqrmrkDate1="23/01/13", rmrkDesc1="-Enter your Query-", rmrkfrom1="800008", more...} 
1 Object { reqrmrkDate1="23/01/13", rmrkDesc1="Allot the budget", rmrkfrom1="800008", more...}
2 Object { reqrmrkDate1="23/01/13", rmrkDesc1="-Enter your Query-", rmrkfrom1="800008", more...}

Comment: The above result is wat my service should return..i can see this in the console..but i see the error also following this..
when i gave an 
alert(data.fillRemarksListResult);
 it returned like this
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

what could be the solution ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use dataType:"json" or JSON.parse..but not both..bcoz it already parses the data and sends it..reparsing ll throw an error obviously !!